# How to install a SSL certificate into Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, azure

I need to install a SSL certificate into Visual Studio for use with an Azure site.  I'm successfully using a self-signed certificate for local development, but I can't figure out how to get my certificate from Comodo to show up in Visual Studio.

I used IIS7 Manager to create the CSR.  I then added the certificate in IIS7 Manager and it appears to be installed correctly.  However, Visual Studio doesn't see it at all.

Should I be using IE to install the certificate?  If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:

1. Use IIS7 Manager to create the CSR
2. Use IIS7 Manager to complete the CSR with they cert returned from the vendor.
3. Use IIS7 Manager to export the cert
4. Use IE's Internet Options to import the cert

Comment: About step 4, You can also double click the .cert file to import it.